# Statements about elements in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb{C}=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{R})\mid a, b\in \mathbb{R}\right \}$ and $u=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \ i=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}$.

I have shown that $\mathbb{C}$ is a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and that $(u,i)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then :

- Show that $(au+bi)(cu+di)=(ac-bd)u+(ad+bc)i$ for all $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and imply that $xy=yx$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$.
- Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that :

(1) $z^t\in \mathbb{C}$ and $zz^t=\delta_zu$

(2) $\delta_z=0_{\mathbb{R}}\iff z=0_{\mathbb{C}}=0_{M_2(\mathbb{R})}$

(3) If $z\neq 0_{\mathbb{C}}$ then $z$ is invertible, $z^{-1}\in \mathbb{C}$ and it holds that $z^{-1}=\delta_z^{-1}z^t$

$$$$

For the first dot I have done the following:

It holds that $u^2=u$, $i^2=-u$ and $ui=i$.

So  we get \begin{equation*}(au+bi)(cu+di)=acu^2+adui+bcui+bdi^2=acu+adi+bci-bdu=(ac-bd)u+(ad+bc)i\end{equation*}
Since each element of $\mathbb{C}$ can be written as a linear combination of $u$ and $i$, we have that $x=au+bi$ and $y=cu+di$.

Then it holds that $xy=yx$ since the coefficients of $(ac-bd)u+(ad+bc)i$ are real numbers, and so the commutativity holds.

Is that correct?

Could you give me a hint for the second dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right to me. For the second dot note that if $z=au+bi$, then $z^{t}=au-bi$ and since $b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $-b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z^{t}\in\mathbb{C}$.  Then use the first dot to calculate: $zz^{t}=(ac-bd)u+(ad+bc)i=(a^2+b^2)u+(-ab+ab)i=(a^2+b^2)u$ (I have used that $z^{t}=cu+di=au-bi$, so: $c=a, d=-b$). Try to do the others on your own, then don't hesitate to ask for help if you need.

P.S. If you are interested, it's not a casuality that it is named $\mathbb{C}$, in fact it is a way to represent the complex numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers

Comment: Ahh I see!! $\delta_z$ is the determinant, isn't it? As for (2) do we do the following?  \begin{equation*}\delta_z=0_{\mathbb{R}}\iff a^2+b^2=0_{\mathbb{R}}\iff a=b=0_{\mathbb{R}}\iff z=0_{\mathbb{C}}\end{equation*} Or isn't that enough/correct? As for (3) do we do the following? If $z\neq 0_{\mathbb{C}}$, then $\delta_z\neq 0_{\mathbb{R}}$, because of (2), and so is $z$ invertible. Or isn't the last implication so trivial?

Comment: @MaryStar it's right. The determinant isn't zero if and only if the rank of the matrix is the greatest. For the last point: $z^{-1}=\delta_z^{-1}z^{t}$ show that $z\cdot \delta_z^{-1}z^{t}=\delta_z^{-1}z^{t}\cdot z=u$ (note that $u$ is the identity element of $\mathbb{C}$). So you conclude since the inverse is unique.

Comment: Having that $z$ is invertible we get that $z^{-1}\in \mathbb{C}$, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar yes, because you show that $z^{-1}=\delta_z^{-1}z^{t}$, and we have previously shown that $z^{t}\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)